# AS3/AIR Load/Save Username progress

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, save

I am creating an Android application created using Flash AS3. The user will input his/her name(instance name`nameField`), click the previous (`btnPrev`) and next (`btnNext`) button and press save (`btnPrev`). After restarting the application, the last frame saved was loaded (with the name).  However if I want to input 2nd user with different name and save it in different frame, will the 2nd user's save progress be retained (without deleting the progress of the 1st user?). The problem, when I type the previous user name progress and press load (`btnLoad`), his saved progress doesn't load. Please help.

I am a newbie in programming. Here is my code so far:

```
*import flash.events.MouseEvent;


var savedstuff:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myStuff");

btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SaveData);
btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LoadData);
btnNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pageNext);
btnPrev.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pagePrev);


function pageNext (e:MouseEvent){
    nextFrame();
}

function pagePrev (e:MouseEvent){
    prevFrame();
}

function SaveData(MouseEvent){
 savedstuff.data.username = nameField.text 
 savedstuff.flush();
 }
function LoadData(MouseEvent){
 if(savedstuff.size>0){ 
 nameField.text = savedstuff.data.username} 
 gotoAndStop(savedstuff.data.saveData);
 }


if(savedstuff.size>0){
nameField.text = savedstuff.data.username}*
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you want to save and load savedstuff for two different users, right ?

Since you always saving everything with the name "myStuff" data will be overwritten every time you save. If you want that per user you might want to add the username to the SharedObject name:

```
var savedstuff:SharedObject;

function SaveData(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var userName:String = nameField.text;
    savedstuff = SharedObject.getLocal(userName + "myStuff");
    savedstuff.data.username = userName;
    savedstuff.flush();
}

function LoadData(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var userName:String = nameField.text;
    savedstuff = SharedObject.getLocal(userName + "myStuff");
    if(savedstuff.size > 0)
    { 
        nameField.text = savedstuff.data.username} 
        gotoAndStop(savedstuff.data.saveData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Hmm, i am currently away from my laptop, will try it later. Will this code load the saved content of each user who used and saved in the application? Also, if I type his/her name in the nameField.text and press the load button, will his/her progress will load? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, that is the idea - different usernames will get an own save file